# IF statement comparing the dates from same column

Tags: powerbi, dax, self-join

I have sql query like below : (have put only skeleton)

```
select 
e1.empname,
case
    when e1.date in {"20201001","20200102"} 
        and e2.date not in {"20200101","20200102","20200103"} then "entry"
    when v1.date > v2.date  then "exit"
    when v1.date < v2.date then "detsined"
    else "promoted"
end as "As usual"
from employee v1, employee v2
where v1.quarter= "2015 Q3"
```

I'm trying to write a equivalent dax measure. IF(table[datestring]>table[datestrin]) this is not working . I understand that we need to use the self join concept here. Can someone help me out here?

Comment: Can you share a sample data with a desired output?

Comment: select e1.empname, case when e1.date in {"20201001","20200102"} and 
e2.date not in {"20200101","20200102","20200103"} then "entry" when v1.date > v2.date then "exit" when v1.date < v2.date
then "detsined" else "promoted" end as "Status" from employee v1, employee v2 

Sample data :

Employee ID  DateString   
1001          20200101     
1002          20120101     
1003          20201229     
1004          20201120
1005          20200912

In Dax, I want to create caluculated column "Status", with the case when condition specified as in sql query. Trying to achieve this in DAX

Comment: Alias e1 and e2 belongs to which tables? Can you provide some sample data? and then show what is your expectation. There should have some way to get reached to your required output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature is not available on power bi